# How could you mark this question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[This question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8844/which-questions-should-be-duplicated-and-which-not), is duplicate to [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8540/how-to-decide-which-question-to-close-as-duplicate), at least you say so, I didn't read any of them.

Anyway the point is that [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8540/how-to-decide-which-question-to-close-as-duplicate) does not have any accepted answer. The other day, I tried to flag a question as duplicate on Askubuntu, (I forgot which one), it didn't allow me to flag it because the other question does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer restriction doesn't apply on meta. Questions without answers can still be used as dupe masters here (thanks to Braiam for clarifying that point).

It wouldn't have mattered anyway though, since a moderator helped close it.

As to whether it is a duplicate, I didn't read them either ;)

Comment: Actually meta doesn't have this restrictions. As you can see 2 users could vote to close. Check my close vote in this question where I marked as duplicated of an unanswered question. ;)

Comment: @Braiam Ah cool. Missed that.