# There is no keyboard shortcut for Unity Dash Previews, yet the question is being marked as a duplicate of the keyboard shortcuts thread

Tags: discussion, duplicates

Two existing questions [[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193871/dash-previews-keyboard-shortcut), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191574/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-dash-previews)] have asked after a keyboard shortcut for accessing the Unity Dash Preview feature, which is currently only accessible with a right-click, and were marked as duplicates of this great keyboard shortcuts thread [[3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/what-are-unitys-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts)]. A keyboard shortcut for accessing Dash Previews isn't in that thread. In fact, the word "preview" is not even mentioned.

In the official documentation, no keyboard shortcut is referenced [[4](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/unity-dash-intro.html)].

There is nothing in the ubuntu-devel-discuss mailing list when I search for the keywords "dash preview" or even "unity preview" [[5](http://www.mail-archive.com/search?q=dash+preview&l=ubuntu-devel-discuss%40lists.ubuntu.com)].

There is no bug yet filed for a feature request [[6](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity?field.searchtext=preview&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=)].

What's the next step? How can I help?

Answer (score 1):

I really hate with all my soul those kind of "catch all"-list questions. It leads to [this kind of situation](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9217/169736) (which I have already [rose awareness](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9136/169736) about this kind of abuse, in [several occasions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8830/169736) and there's actually a [moderator that says the same](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8830/dont-start-to-vote-for-closing-as-duplicate-for-questions-whose-answers-cant-b#comment16799_8830)) and actually adding the information to the "master" just obscures more the information.

**I'm voting to reopen both questions again.** Both deserves their own answer.

They are not asking for a "list of all shortcuts of unity" as the master does but shortcut to a specific action of the GUI and ergo in the nature different questions.

Comment: It seems that linking to the master thread would be okay if only each of the questions were answered first by informing the askers that the master list contains all known shortcuts, but sorry, there isn't one yet for Dash Previews, and oh, by the way, here's how to request/encourage that one be programmed into Unity. As it is, marking each of these as a duplicate is not only lazy, but actually false.

Comment: I think the best thing for these users is to be educated on what a good next step would be instead of being fed a dead end. Perhaps they could be directed to the [Reporting Bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) page.